# ODE Problem (Differentiating by function)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I'm trying to solve the following ODE:

$x' = (t+x)^2$

I was hinted that $dx/dt = 1/(dt/dx)$, which I assume suggests I should derive $t$ with regard to $x$, I'm not sure how to formally justify it and would appreciate some help understanding what is desired and how to justify it.

Thanks.

Comment: The equation itself entails that any solution $x$ is such that $x'$ is non-negative and therefore it is increasing. It would be nice to prove that any solution is strictly increasing so you can be sure about $x$ being invertible. But if $x$ is constant on an interval, then the [Picard–Lindelöf theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard%E2%80%93Lindel%C3%B6f_theorem) implies it will be so on all its domain. But it can be checked by inspection that no constant function can be a solution to the ODE, thus $x'$ is non negative and $x$ is strictly increasing, which makes it invertible.

Comment: Alas I don't know how to use this information to solve the ODE.

Comment: To solve use $v=x+t$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $z(t) := t + x(t) \Rightarrow z'(t) = 1 + x'(t)$. Therefore,
$$
z'(t) = 1 + z^2(t) \Rightarrow \int \frac{\mathrm{d}z}{1+z^2} = \tan^{-1}(z) = \tan^{-1}(t + x(t)) = t + c_1.
$$

Solving for $x(t)$,
$$
\boxed{x(t) = \tan(t+c_1) - t.}
$$